# Create new column based on groupby shift in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Session      slot_num        Overbook     ID
s1           1               no           A
s1           2               no           B
s1           2               yes          B
s1           3               no           C
s1           4               no           D
s1           4               yes          D
s1           5               no           E
s1           6               no           F
s1           7               no           G
s2           1               no           A1
s2           2               no           B1
s2           2               no           C1
s2           3               yes          C1
s2           4               no           D1
s2           4               no           E1
s2           5               no           F1
s2           6               no           G1
s2           5               yes          G1
```

Step1:
From the above I would like to create a column Overbook1, which is the shifted version of Overbook upwards as shown below by groupby session.

Now we get

```
Session      slot_num        Overbook     ID    Overbook1
s1           1               no           A     no
s1           2               no           B     yes
s1           2               yes          B     no
s1           3               no           C     no
s1           4               no           D     yes
s1           4               yes          D     no
s1           5               no           E     no
s1           6               no           F     no
s1           7               no           G     no
s2           1               no           A1    yes   
s2           2               yes          A1    no
s2           2               no           K1    yes
s2           3               yes          K1    no
s2           4               no           D1    no
s2           4               no           L1    no
s2           5               no           S1    no
s2           6               no           G1    yes
s2           5               yes          G1    no
```

Step2: Delete the rows where Overbook == 'yes'

Final Expected output:

```
Session      slot_num        Overbook     ID    Overbook1
s1           1               no           A     no
s1           2               no           B     yes
s1           3               no           C     no
s1           4               no           D     yes
s1           5               no           E     no
s1           6               no           F     no
s1           7               no           G     no
s2           1               no           A1    yes   
s2           2               no           K1    yes
s2           4               no           D1    no
s2           4               no           L1    no
s2           5               no           S1    no
s2           6               no           G1    yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Overbook1'] = df.groupby('Session')['Overbook'].shift(-1, fill_value='no')

df = df[df['Overbook'].ne('yes')]
print (df)
    Session  slot_num Overbook  ID Overbook1
0       s1         1       no   A        no
1       s1         2       no   B       yes
3       s1         3       no   C        no
4       s1         4       no   D       yes
6       s1         5       no   E        no
7       s1         6       no   F        no
8       s1         7       no   G        no
9       s2         1       no  A1        no
10      s2         2       no  B1        no
11      s2         2       no  C1       yes
13      s2         4       no  D1        no
14      s2         4       no  E1        no
15      s2         5       no  F1        no
16      s2         6       no  G1       yes
```

Comment: pls look into this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61496685/create-new-rows-based-on-values-of-one-of-the-columns-in-the-above-row-with-spec

Only your level is possible. I tried some... it is giving half of the desired out put

Comment: @ALI - Unfortunately today a bit busy, so I have no time (for complicated solution like this, unfortuantely), sorry :(

Comment: Ooh, I am really sorry for disturbing you. Thank you so much for your reply..

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to create a new column:

```
df['Overbook1'] = df.groupby('Session').Overbook\
    .apply(lambda s: s.shift(-1, fill_value='no'))
```

And the second - select only "wanted" rows:

```
df = df.query('Overbook == "no"')
```