# create new rows based on values of one of the columns in the above row with specific condition - pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
B_ID   no_show  Session  slot_num  walkin   ns_w   c_ns_w     c_walkin
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.2    0.2    0.2       0.2
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.5   -0.2    0.2       0.7 
    3     0.8       S1        3       0.5    0.3    0.5       1.2  
    4     0.3       S1        4       0.8   -0.5    0.0       2.0
    5     0.6       S1        5       0.4    0.2    0.2       2.4 
    6     0.8       S1        6       0.2    0.6    0.8       2.6 
    7     0.9       S1        7       0.1    0.8    1.4       2.7
    8     0.4       S1        8       0.5   -0.1    1.3       3.2
    9     0.6       S1        9       0.1    0.5    1.8       3.3
    12    0.9       S2        1       0.9    0.0    0.0       0.9
    13    0.5       S2        2       0.4    0.1    0.1       1.3  
    14    0.3       S2        3       0.1    0.2    0.3       1.4    
    15    0.7       S2        4       0.4    0.3    0.6       1.8  
    20    0.7       S2        5       0.1    0.6    1.2       1.9
    16    0.6       S2        6       0.3    0.3    1.5       2.2
    17    0.8       S2        7       0.5    0.3    1.8       2.7
    19    0.3       S2        8       0.8   -0.5    1.3       3.5
```

where,

`df[ns_w] =  df['no_show'] - df['walkin']`

`c_ns_w = cumulaitve of ns_w`

`df['c_ns_w'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['ns_w'].cumsum()`

`c_walkin = cumulative of walkin`

`df['c_walkin'] = df.groupby(['Session'])['walkin'].cumsum()`

From the above I would like to calculate two columns called `u_ns_w` and `u_c_walkin`.

And when ever `u_c_walkin  > 0.9` create a new row with `no_show = 0`, `walkin=0` and all other values will be same as the above row. where `B_ID = walkin1, 2, etc,` and subtract `1` from the above `u_c_walkin`.

At the same time when ever `u_c_ns_w  > 0.8`  add a new row with `B_ID = overbook1, 2 etc`, with `no_show = 0.5, walkin=0, ns_w = 0.5` and all other values same as above row and subtract `0.5` from the above `u_c_ns_w`.

Expected output:

```
B_ID   no_show  Session  slot_num  walkin   ns_w   c_ns_w  c_walkin  u_c_walkin  u_c_ns_w
    1     0.4       S1        1       0.2    0.2    0.2    0.2       0.2          0.2
    2     0.3       S1        2       0.5   -0.2    0.2    0.7       0.7          0.2
    3     0.8       S1        3       0.5    0.3    0.5    1.2       1.2          0.5
walkin1   0.0       S1        3       0.0    0.3    0.5    1.2       0.2          0.5
    4     0.3       S1        4       0.8   -0.5    0.0    2.0       1.0          0.0
walkin2   0.0       S1        4       0.0   -0.5    0.0    2.0       0.0          0.0
    5     0.6       S1        5       0.4    0.2    0.2    2.4       0.4          0.2
    6     0.8       S1        6       0.2    0.6    0.8    2.6       0.6          0.8
    7     0.9       S1        7       0.1    0.8    1.4    2.7       0.7          1.4
overbook1 0.5       S1        7       0.0    0.5    1.4    2.7       0.7          0.9
    8     0.4       S1        8       0.5   -0.1    1.3    3.2       1.2          0.8
walkin3   0.0       S1        8       0.0   -0.1    1.3    3.2       0.2          0.8
    9     0.6       S1        9       0.1    0.5    1.8    3.3       0.1          1.3
overbook2 0.5       S1        9       0.0    0.5    1.8    3.3       0.1          0.8
    12    0.9       S2        1       0.9    0.0    0.0    0.9       0.9          0.0     
    13    0.5       S2        2       0.4    0.1    0.1    1.3       1.3          0.1
walkin1   0.0       S2        2       0.0    0.1    0.1    1.3       0.3          0.1
    14    0.3       S2        3       0.1    0.2    0.3    1.4       0.4          0.3
    15    0.7       S2        4       0.4    0.3    0.6    1.8       0.8          0.6
    20    0.7       S2        5       0.1    0.6    1.2    1.9       0.9          1.2
overbook1 0.5       S2        5       0.0    0.5    1.2    1.9       0.9          0.7
    16    0.6       S2        6       0.3    0.3    1.5    2.2       1.2          1.0
walkin2   0.0       S2        6       0.3    0.3    1.5    2.2       0.2          1.0
overbook2 0.5       S2        6       0.0    0.5    1.5    2.2       0.2          0.5
    17    0.8       S2        7       0.5    0.3    1.8    2.7       0.7          0.8
    19    0.3       S2        8       0.8   -0.5    1.3    3.5       1.5          0.3
walkin3   0.0       S2        8       0.8   -0.5    1.3    3.5       0.5          0.3
```

I tried below code to create the walkin rows but not able to create for overbook rows.

```
def create_u_columns (ser):
    l_index = []
    arr_ns = ser.to_numpy()
    # array for latter insert
    arr_idx = np.zeros(len(ser), dtype=int)
    walkin_id = 1
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)-1):
        if arr_ns[i]>0.8:
            # remove 1 to u_no_show
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= 1
            # increment later idx to add
            arr_idx[i] = walkin_id
            walkin_id +=1
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'u_cumulative': arr_ns, 'mask_idx':arr_idx}, index=ser.index)

df[['u_c_walkin', 'mask_idx']]= df.groupby(['Session'])['c_walkin'].apply(create_u_columns)


# select the rows
df_toAdd = df.loc[df['mask_idx'].astype(bool), :].copy()
# replace the values as wanted
df_toAdd['no_show'] = 0
df_toAdd['walkin'] = 0
df_toAdd['EpisodeNumber'] = 'walkin'+df_toAdd['mask_idx'].astype(str)
df_toAdd['u_c_walkin'] -= 1
# add 0.5 to index for later sort
df_toAdd.index += 0.5 

new_df = pd.concat([df,df_toAdd]).sort_index()\
           .reset_index(drop=True).drop('mask_idx', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can modify the function this way to do both check at the same time. Please check that it is exactly the conditions you want to apply for the walkin and overbook dataframes.

```
def create_columns(dfg):
    arr_walkin = dfg['c_walkin'].to_numpy()
    arr_ns = dfg['c_ns_w'].to_numpy()
    # array for latter insert
    arr_idx_walkin = np.zeros(len(arr_walkin), dtype=int)
    arr_idx_ns = np.zeros(len(arr_ns), dtype=int)
    walkin_id = 1
    oberbook_id = 1
    for i in range(len(arr_ns)):
        # condition on c_walkin
        if arr_walkin[i]>0.9:
            # remove 1 to u_no_show
            arr_walkin[i+1:] -= 1
            # increment later idx to add
            arr_idx_walkin[i] = walkin_id
            walkin_id +=1
        # condition on c_ns_w
        if arr_ns[i]>0.8:
            # remove 1 to u_no_show
            arr_ns[i+1:] -= 0.5
            # increment later idx to add
            arr_idx_ns[i] = oberbook_id
            oberbook_id +=1
    #return a dataframe with both columns
    return pd.DataFrame({'u_c_walkin': arr_walkin, 
                         'u_c_ns_w': arr_ns,
                         'mask_idx_walkin':arr_idx_walkin, 
                         'mask_idx_ns': arr_idx_ns }, index=dfg.index)

df[['u_c_walkin', 'u_c_ns_w', 'mask_idx_walkin', 'mask_idx_ns']]=\
   df.groupby(['Session'])[['c_walkin', 'c_ns_w']].apply(create_columns)


# select the rows for walkin
df_walkin = df.loc[df['mask_idx_walkin'].astype(bool), :].copy()
# replace the values as wanted
df_walkin['no_show'] = 0
df_walkin['walkin'] = 0
df_walkin['B_ID'] = 'walkin'+df_walkin['mask_idx_walkin'].astype(str)
df_walkin['u_c_walkin'] -= 1
# add 0.5 to index for later sort
df_walkin.index += 0.2 

# select the rows for ns_w
df_ns = df.loc[df['mask_idx_ns'].astype(bool), :].copy()
# replace the values as wanted
df_ns['no_show'] = 0.5
df_ns['walkin'] = 0
df_ns['ns_w'] = 0.5
df_ns['B_ID'] = 'overbook'+df_ns['mask_idx_ns'].astype(str)
df_ns['u_c_ns_w'] -= 0.5
# add 0.5 to index for later sort
df_ns.index += 0.4

new_df = pd.concat([df,df_walkin, df_ns]).sort_index()\
           .reset_index(drop=True).drop(['mask_idx_walkin','mask_idx_ns'], axis=1)
```

and you get:

```
print (new_df)
         B_ID  no_show Session  slot_num  walkin  ns_w  c_ns_w  c_walkin  \
0           1      0.4      S1         1     0.2   0.2     0.2       0.2   
1           2      0.3      S1         2     0.5  -0.2     0.2       0.7   
2           3      0.8      S1         3     0.5   0.3     0.5       1.2   
3     walkin1      0.0      S1         3     0.0   0.3     0.5       1.2   
4           4      0.3      S1         4     0.8  -0.5     0.0       2.0   
5     walkin2      0.0      S1         4     0.0  -0.5     0.0       2.0   
6           5      0.6      S1         5     0.4   0.2     0.2       2.4   
7           6      0.8      S1         6     0.2   0.6     0.8       2.6   
8           7      0.9      S1         7     0.1   0.8     1.4       2.7   
9   overbook1      0.5      S1         7     0.0   0.5     1.4       2.7   
10          8      0.4      S1         8     0.5  -0.1     1.3       3.2   
11    walkin3      0.0      S1         8     0.0  -0.1     1.3       3.2   
12          9      0.6      S1         9     0.1   0.5     1.8       3.3   
13  overbook2      0.5      S1         9     0.0   0.5     1.8       3.3   
14         12      0.9      S2         1     0.9   0.0     0.0       0.9   
15         13      0.5      S2         2     0.4   0.1     0.1       1.3   
16    walkin1      0.0      S2         2     0.0   0.1     0.1       1.3   
17         14      0.3      S2         3     0.1   0.2     0.3       1.4   
18         15      0.7      S2         4     0.4   0.3     0.6       1.8   
19         20      0.7      S2         5     0.1   0.6     1.2       1.9   
20  overbook1      0.5      S2         5     0.0   0.5     1.2       1.9   
21         16      0.6      S2         6     0.3   0.3     1.5       2.2   
22    walkin2      0.0      S2         6     0.0   0.3     1.5       2.2   
23  overbook2      0.5      S2         6     0.0   0.5     1.5       2.2   
24         17      0.8      S2         7     0.5   0.3     1.8       2.7   
25         19      0.3      S2         8     0.8  -0.5     1.3       3.5   
26    walkin3      0.0      S2         8     0.0  -0.5     1.3       3.5   

    u_c_walkin  u_c_ns_w  
0          0.2       0.2  
1          0.7       0.2  
2          1.2       0.5  
3          0.2       0.5  
4          1.0       0.0  
5          0.0       0.0  
6          0.4       0.2  
7          0.6       0.8  
8          0.7       1.4  
9          0.7       0.9  
10         1.2       0.8  
11         0.2       0.8  
12         0.3       1.3  
13         0.3       0.8  
14         0.9       0.0  
15         1.3       0.1  
16         0.3       0.1  
17         0.4       0.3  
18         0.8       0.6  
19         0.9       1.2  
20         0.9       0.7  
21         1.2       1.0  
22         0.2       1.0  
23         1.2       0.5  
24         0.7       0.8  
25         1.5       0.3  
26         0.5       0.3
```

Comment: Hi Ben is it possible to iterarate over a list. this where  we can change (arr_ns[i]>0.8) [0.8, 0.9, 1.0] and create 3 df such as new_df_0.8, new_df_0.9 and new_df_1.0

Comment: pls look above comment. if possible pls help

Comment: @Danish yes it is possible, when you create the function you can add a parameter like `create_columns(dfg, threshold_ns=0.8)` and then change in this function `if arr_ns[i]>0.8` by `if arr_ns[i]>threshold_ns`. Then when you call the apply, you can pass this argument with for example `df.groupby(['Session'])[['c_walkin', 'c_ns_w']].apply(lambda x: create_columns(x, 0.9))`. For the rest, it would be good to either create a function that do all the rest of the manipulation, or a loop for over the values of threshold. In both case, don't forget to create copy of your original dataframe :)

Comment: @Danish I don't have much time for it now, but I'll try later

Comment: during your free pls look into below question.. new question.. no one answered..similar to above question with slight modification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306761/create-new-rows-based-specific-condition-and-iterate-over-a-list-in-pandas

Comment: @Danish I answered your other question, the principle with the loop and how to define the threshold would be the same idea if you want to use it with this version of the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408422/create-a-function-to-create-new-rows-in-data-frames-based-on-the-given-parameter?noredirect=1#comment110376357_62408422
pls look into this question during your free time. similar to above question with slight modification.

Comment: Pls look into below question. No one answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982000/replace-the-column-values-based-on-the-list-dictionary-and-specific-date-conditi